# exception nativeEvalAndFetch: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I keep getting an error with Angular and Ionic, running on iOS simulator.

When running

```
ionic run ios
```

It was launching on the simulator fine. Then I pressed the home button on the simulator and got

> exception nativeEvalAndFetch : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova

I was testing for deeplinking on my ionic app and this broke it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to fix, I put

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

In my header. I had

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

So now I have both in the header and it is working fine. Not sure if I need both or not, but it works.

Also, my phonegap.js lives in my app folder. So I add to the gruntfile so it will copy over when I grunt build.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me when I removed a plugin on another branch. What I had to do is manually remove plugin and remove plugin info from package and config.